# Filter MySQL ResultSet with C++

Tags: c++, mysql

Is there a way to filter a MySQL ResultSet? I'm making a massive 2D MMO style game. I have a MySQL table of the map defined as : row, col, layer, tile_id. On the server I'm going to be sending chunks of the map to the client as they move around to make a seamless world for the clients.

I have everything setup for this, but I would like to avoid hitting the database so much while I loop through the row/col that each player requires, so I do a couple big queries that return me the row/col info. Once I have this ResultSet while I'm looking for row/col I'd like to just filter the ResultSet for these values to get the tile_id. So my question is, can I just filter the ResultSet that has all the data I know I need from the query I already ran to populate it?

Doing this in C++.

Again, I don't want to hit the DB again after my original query so this has to be in C++ and not sql. I just don't want to pound on the DB and making a bigger read vs a ton of smaller reads seems more efficient.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I'm doing. At some level this has to get into a 2D array, but now that you say this and I think about it I could probably just do that on the client side instead of on the server side, and on the server side just send the data as is (don't put it into a 2D array before sending). For some reason I was thinking I needed to put it into a 2D array on the server, but maybe not.

Comment: It doesn't exactly sound like your map should be in a relational database at all, if it's a simple 2D array of `{layer, tile_id}`

Comment: What other options are you suggesting? The map is planned to be massive so I can't store the entire thing in memory on the server, which is why I wanted it in a DB. I only have to query the table to get subsets of the map for each client. Send them the data and not store any of it in memory on the server. Text files are out as querying those would take too long.

Comment: I haven't exactly delved too deep into such matters, but perhaps you could store more than just one tile on the same row? I know storing blobs isn't necessarily the best idea - but on the other hand, this sounds somewhat inefficient too. Regarding other possibilities, a simple binary format could work relatively fast for reading but writing might have issues.

Comment: I'm testing things out myself so I might look into some of those. So far the DB seems to be working pretty well and fast. I think I might just send the records as is to the clients though and convert them to 2D arrays on their side.

Comment: You are dealing with geographic data, are you using the mysql related functionalities?

Comment: Didn't even know that existed. Any ideal ways I can get started with looking at this functionality?

Comment: why not store the map on the clients computer? if this is for a video game? If your game every becomes very popular what than?

Comment: The entire map can be modified. Pretty much nothing is static. So I need this data stored in a central place. If it becomes popular all the more reason the server needs to control everything because it'll get more ppl wanting to cheat.

Comment: @pyCthon, sorry this is an MMO (as posted) so it's 100% online.

Comment: You could use more detailed SQL `select` queries to reduce the result set.  Also search the web for `database normal form` to see if you can rearrange the tables to reduce the size of the result set.

Comment: I never used them myself, the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/spatial-extensions.html) is very thorough, it's probably not the best place to start.

Comment: The interesting point of this extension is the possibility to do select on regions, with various operators (overlaps, within, intersect, etc.). The indexing model is made for that purpose, so you could rely on doing several queries, instead of doing the filtering yourself.